# What is the "Moose" worm and how can I protect myself from it?

Tags: exploit, vulnerability, zero-day, router

I have heard from others that there is a new worm called "moose". This actively targets and exploits home routers.

What are the effects of this exploit?

How can I protect myself from this?

Can I check if my router is vulnerable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ESET released [a report about the vulnerability here](http://www.welivesecurity.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/Dissecting-LinuxMoose.pdf). Their key findings are:

> - Linux/Moose targets consumer routers and modems including the hardware provided by Internet Service Providers (ISPs) to consumers
> - The threat is built for deep network penetration spreading past firewalls
> - It can eavesdrop on communications to and from devices connected behind the infected router, including desktops, laptops and mobile
>     phones
> - Moose runs a comprehensive proxy service (SOCKS and HTTP) that can be accessed only by a specific list of IP addresses
> - The operators use the infected devices to perform social network fraud on Twitter, Facebook, Instagram, Youtube and more
> - Moose can be configured to reroute router DNS traffic, which enables man-in-the-middle attacks from across the Internet
> - It affects Linux-based embedded devices running on the MIPS and ARM architectures

If we look at how it spreads one statement is very important here:

> Last but not least, this threat spreads only by compromising systems
>   with weak or default credentials. No vulnerabilities are exploited by
>   the malware. Although downplayed by system administrators, this attack
>   vector has been effective at compromising a lot of Internet-connected
>   systems. As FireEye recently stated: “Brute forcing credentials
>   remains one of the top 10 most common ways an organization is first
>   breached.

They have listed a some of the devices which may be affected:

**Network equipment vendors**

3Com, Alcatel-Lucent, Allied Telesis, Avaya, Belkin, Brocade, Buffalo, Celerity, Cisco,
D-link, Enterasys, Hewlett-Packard, Huawei, Linksys, Mikrotik, Netgear, Meridian, Nortel,
SpeedStream, Thomson, TP-Link, Zhone, ZyXEL

**Appliances vendors**

APC, Brother, Konica/Minolta, Kyocera, Microplex, Ricoh, Toshiba, Xerox

**Internet of Things vendors**

Hik Vision, Leviton

**Indicators of compromise**

> If the credentials can be used via Telnet to login, if Telnet is
>   enabled by default and if a shell access can be obtained by typing sh
>   in the device’s prompt, then these are very good indicators that a
>   device could be infected by Linux/Moose.

**Prevention**

> Change default passwords on network equipment even if it is not
>   reachable from the Internet. Disable Telnet login and use SSH where
>   possible. Make sure that your router is not accessible from the
>   Internet on ports 22 (SSH), 23 (Telnet), 80 (HTTP) and 443 (HTTPS). If
>   you are unsure about how to perform this test, when you are at home,
>   use the "common ports" scan from the ShieldsUP service from GRC.com.
>   Make sure that the above mentioned ports receive a Stealth or Closed
>   status. Running the latest firmware available from your embedded
>   device vendor is also recommended.

Comment: Keep in mind that the "ShieldsUP service from GRC.com" is a product created by Steve Gibson, who has demonstrated a fantastic lack of understanding of network technologies. He's a salesman and pundit, not a security expert. There are numerous reports that ShieldsUP doesn't actually properly scan ports, and may return both false positives and false negatives.